# Custom Objective Function Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I need to define my own loss function, I am using GAN model and my loss will include both adverserial loss and L1 loss between true and generated images.

I tried to write a function but the following error:

```
ValueError: ('Could not interpret loss function identifier:', Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0)
```

My loss function is:

```
def loss_function(y_true, y_pred, y_true1, y_pred1):

    bce=0
    for i in range (64):
        a = y_pred1[i]        
        b = y_true1[i]        
        x = K.log(a)
        bce=bce-x
    bce/=64
    print('bce = ', bce)

    for i in zip( y_pred, y_true):
        img   = i[0]
        image = np.zeros((64,64),dtype=y_pred.dtype)
        image = img[0,:,:]                
        image = image*127.5+127.5                
        imgfinal = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))

        img1 = i[1]
        image1 = np.zeros((64,64), dtype=y_true.dtype)
        image1 = img1[0,:,:]
        image1 = image1*127.5+127.5              
        imgfinal1 = Image.fromarray(image1.astype(np.uint8))

        diff = ImageChops.difference(imgfinal,imgfinal1)
        h = diff.histogram()
        sq = (value*((idx%256)**2) for idx, value in enumerate(h))       
        sum_of_squares = sum(sq)
        lossr = math.sqrt(sum_of_squares/float(im1.size[0] * im1.size[1]))
        loss  = loss+lossr

    loss /=(64*127) 
    print('loss = ', loss)

    return x+loss
```

Comment: could you trace the error to the line that is throwing it?

Comment: discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss = loss_function(y_true ,y_pred ,y_true1 ,y_pred1), optimizer=g_optim)  - This is the line which is throwing error, this is where I am calling this loss_function.

Comment: Can you trace it to what line *inside* your custom loss function the error originates?

Comment: Error is not originating inside the loss function, but the keras is not able to identify my loss function.

Comment: Based on your comment I added an answer, it would also help to include that line of code you mentioned in your answer... im going to edit so

Answer (score 4):

From your comment you say you are passing your custom function to the compile operation like this:

```
discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss = loss_function(y_true ,y_pred ,y_true1 ,y_pred1), optimizer=g_optim)
```

However, according to the [docs](https://keras.io/losses/) you should be passing your custom function like:

```
discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss = loss_function, optimizer=g_optim)
```

You can take a look at this github [discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/369) where they also indicate how to use custom loss functions.

**Note**: As you require 4 parameters in your function and it is only expected to have 2 at most, you can do something as suggested in this github [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2121), which involves defining a container function that handles those extra parameters, something like:

```
def loss_function(y_true1, y_pred1):
    def my_nested_function(y_true, y_pred):
        #now you can work with all 4 variables here
```

and passing it as parameter when compiling like:

```
discriminator_on_generator.compile(loss=loss_function(y_true1, y_pred1), optimizer=g_optim)
```

Alternatively, you could *merge* your 4 parameters into 2 (y_true, y_predict) and then inside your single function split them into your 4 variables (y_true, y_pred, y_true1, y_predict1), as they also discuss in that issue.

Comment: I tried this already, It gave the error :- Given two arguements to loss function  whereas four are required.  Because by default loss function only takes two parameters y_true and y_pred.

Comment: Editing my question to show how you can handle that

Comment: Thanks, I am also trying something like this.

Comment: Ok, let me know if it works. It seems that by calling the function the way I indicated solved your original problem (function not recognized), as now you get a new error. The edits I added should solve your *new* problem. If those new problems persist let me know or consider asking/searching for other questions

Comment: I tried it but the same error occured, I think it's because my function is not in theano or tensorflow.

Comment: You tried both doing nested functions and merge/split your variables?

Comment: Actually I only tried by merging and splitting my variable not with nested function yet, and I have re-written my function in theano backend also, but the error still persists. and I also need to pass the parameters y_pred and y_true while calling otherwise it's not working.

Comment: I modified my answer to better help you. I added the way you should compile your model. I also edited the definition of the wrapper function, as the extra parameters should be on the "outer" function, leaving the default ones to the nested function. Reading the github issue will probably give you a better understanding of what I am saying in case you still have doubts. Do try it and let me know